# webflow in grails application

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

how can i redirect to the same state more than one time using web flow
ex:

```
on('submit'){
    def destinationInstance = Destination.get(params.destination)
    def destinationGroupsInstance = DestinationGroup.get(params.destinationGroups)
    def h = destinationInstance.addToDestinationGroups(destinationGroupsInstance)
}.to('flowList')
```

what i need is how to enter to this state more than one time until destinations ends
thx

Comment: I find it very difficult to understand the question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on('submit'){
   def destinationInstance = Destination.get(params.destination)
   def destinationGroupsInstance = DestinationGroup.get(params.destinationGroups)
   def h = destinationInstance.addToDestinationGroups(destinationGroupsInstance)
}.to{
   (condition or while loop or for loop)
   if success then 
      return "<state name>"
   else
      return "flowList"
}
```

**Reference:**
http://livesnippets.cloudfoundry.com/docs/guide/2.%20Grails%20webflow%20plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd probably have something like the following code, which is untested but may give you a general idea.

```
def destinationFlow = {

    initialize {
        action {
            flow.destination = Destination.get(params.id)
        }
        on('success').to 'destinationList'
    }

    destinationList {
        render(view: 'destinationList')
        on('addDestination') {
            def destinationGroup = DestinationGroup.get(params.destinationGroupId)
            flow.destination.addToDestinationGroups(destinationGroup)
        }.to 'destinationList'

        on('finish').to 'done'
    }

    done {
        flow.destination.save()
        redirect(...) // out of the flow
    }
}
```

You'll need buttons on your `destinationList` view that invoke the 'addDestination' or 'finish' actions. See the [WebFlow documentation](http://www.grails.org/WebFlow) and [Reference Guide](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.5%20Web%20Flow).

Comment: on submit i need to add the destinationGroup to destination, but not once. what's i meaning that i need to redirect to this page until all destination have destinationGroup. i find a way to redirect to the same page but i have a problem that saving in database didn't happen. do you have any solution for this problem

Comment: That's kind of confusing. If that's the case, why is a webflow needed? Why can't you just loop over all the available Destinations, adding the group to each? I'm probably misunderstanding what you're asking. Perhaps you can describe what your Destination and DestinationGroup entities are so that we can understand your domain.